# Stop EKS/Traefik overwriting Inbound Security Group rules every 2 weeks

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, traefik

I have a kubernetes cluster (EKS AWS Managed) with Traefik Ingress service installed. Now, my understanding is the ingress service creates and manages the load balancer in AWS, and also the security group.

Problem is; it keeps creating inbound rules which open port 80/443 to 0.0.0.0/0, and I want to restrict them to specific IPs.

I change the security groups manually, but exactly two weeks (CloudTrail logs) later, they get overriden with the defaults.

Any ideas how to stop this?

I checked the traefik docs, but couldn't obviously see anything in there that handles this.